# What is the size of Option<u64> in instruction data for an anchor program ix?

Tags: anchor, instructions

Assuming u64 is 8 bytes what is Option<u64>. How many bytes extra does Option add to the instruction data for an anchor program ix?

Answer (score 3):

An `Option<T>'s` size is `1 + Size(T)` according to the [space reference](https://book.anchor-lang.com/anchor_references/space.html).